# C# Cannot Get Synonyms Using Interop

Tags: c#, synonym

Im trying to use Synonyms in my program.
I added the Ref to Word's Interop.
Unfortunately, when I try to look for get_SynonymInfo function, I do not have that one in my options.

[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: It's an indexer. So, you'd use `wordApp.SynonymInfo[...]`

Answer (score -1):

Try this example:

Add using:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

Add the following code to a method:

```
var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
string simpleWord = "hello";
SynonymInfo s = word.SynonymInfo[simpleWord];
foreach (var meaning in s.MeaningList as Array)
{
     MessageBox.Show((string)meaning);
}
```

You should get "ciao" as output

Comment: Second, I get an exception while running: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in SearchEngineInterface.exe

Additional information: Word cannot start the thesaurus." Do u know y?

Comment: You may need to install dictionary in your Microsoft office